# Overcurrent Sandisk SDSSDHII-960G... any hope?

Tags: ssd, power

I have a SanDisk SSD (SDSSDHII-960G) that I have used on and off for several years. In mid December I used it as the boot disk for a fresh install of Ubuntu 20, conventionally connected to the motherboard via SATA. The install was successful in the sense that I could power it off, remove the installation thumb drive, reboot and get a desktop. Then I forgot about the project and left the case open for the past two or three weeks. I have humidifiers but sometimes the humidity in my apartment drops to 15%. I don't do anything else to manage static.

Today I couldn't boot with the drive cabled up. When I disconnected the drive, the computer would boot but complain about the lack of a boot device. Then I connected the drive via a USB3 to SATA cable and got a USB over-current warning during POST.

**Is there anything I could try to salvage the drive? It's an old drive and I don't think there's anything on there besides the fresh OS, but I don't feel like giving up quite yet.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSD Drives generally do not respond to retries; HDD sometimes do (but not always).

So if you cannot read it, the drive is gone.

If you have data on it that you need, you might contact a local recovery agency.

I would not trust an old SSD drive with errors to a new OS, so you should replace the drive for a fresh OS install.

Good luck